# Shifter only clicks in one direction

Tags: derailleur, shifter

My bike shifters on both the front and rear derailleurs suddenly stopped wanting to shift down. They both shift up no problem and the cable looks fine but when I try to shift down on either of them the shifter moves with no resistance at all, doesn't click and the cable doesn't move. Everything was working fine yesterday but it dropped below freezing today for the first time this fall and I think that has something to do with it. I just can't figure out what could have frozen because the shifters move just fine in one direction and the cable has no problem.

Comment: How old is the bike? The grease inside shifters gets stiffer over time, and stiffer in the cold. When you try to go the way it doesn't click, is it stiff, or does it move too freely?

Comment: Has the bike been dropped on its right-side ?  Did you park it in a public place and its been damaged ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by shift down? Most people use shift down to mean going into an easier gear (going to a smaller cog in front, larger in rear). But I get the feeling this is not what you mean. Are you able to increase tension front&back, but not release it?

Comment: Sorry yeah I mean shifting to a smaller cog on both derailleurs. I can get them both to shift up in size but not down.

Comment: The bike is about five years old but I don't think it's a grease issur as the shifter moves too freely. There's no resistance at all and it doesn't click. And no, the bike hasn't been dropped, was just sitting in my driveway so I don't think it could have been hit but I'm curious how that would affect it

Comment: How about bringing the bike inside to see if warming it  bit up helps? Secondly, do the shifters regulate the tension in the gear wire as it should? Making them go from almost no tension to full tension? If that is the case then the issue is at the deraileurs (springs frozen in ice?, someone messed with your limit screws??, debris?). If the tension never is released then the issue is probably in the shifters themselves of which I have no experience. Have you tried pulling manually at the wire? while shifting "down"?